# Magento 2.3.2 Object doesn't support property or method 'registerDataModifier'

Tags: magento2.3.2, recaptcha, internet-explorer

I have updated my site from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2. In doing some testing I have found that on checkout in IE it just hangs. The reason is this error in the console-

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'registerDataModifier'
captcha.js (44,21)
```

And here is that code-

```
  //Add captcha code to coupon-apply request.
                setCouponCodeAction.registerDataModifier(function (headers) {
                    if (self.isRequired()) {
                        headers['X-Captcha'] = self.captchaValue()();
                    }
                });
```

This is core Magento 2.3.2 code, it is not an extension. I have not made any changes or modified the code. It works fine in both Chrome and Firefox. What is the best way to resolve this?